# What does "type PDW = ^dword;" mean in delphi?

Tags: delphi

While convert delphi code to C, I found something complex point.

The below is full code of delphi

```
unit resizeunit;

{ resize bm1 to fit in bm2
  bm1,bm2 bitmaps must be created and width,height set }

interface

uses windows,graphics;

procedure BMresize;

var bm1,bm2 : Tbitmap;

implementation

type PDW = ^dword;

procedure BMresize;
//copy bm1 to bm2
var ps0,pd0,psStep,pdStep : dword;       //scanline[0], row steps
    sx1,sy1,sx2,sy2 : single;             //source field positions
    x,y,i,j,destwidth,destheight : word;  //source,dest field pixels
    destR,destG,destB : single;           //destination colors
    sR,sG,sB : byte;                      //source colors
    fx,fy,fix,fiy,dyf : single;           //factors
    fxstep,fystep, dx,dy : single;
    color : dword;
    pdy,pdx,psi,psj : dword;
    AP : single;
    istart,iend,jstart,jend : word;
    devX1,devX2,devY1,devY2 : single;
begin
 ps0 := DWORD(bm1.scanline[0]);
 psstep := ps0 - DWORD(bm1.scanline[1]);
 pd0 := DWORD(bm2.scanline[0]);
 pdstep := pd0 - DWORD(bm2.scanline[1]);
 destwidth := bm2.Width-1;
 destheight := bm2.Height-1;
 fx := bm1.width/ bm2.width;
 fy := bm1.height/bm2.height;
 fix := 1/fx;
 fiy := 1/fy;
 fxstep := 0.9999 * fx;
 fystep := 0.9999 * fy;
 pdy := pd0;
 for y := 0 to destheight do         //vertical destination pixels
  begin
   sy1 := fy * y;
   sy2 := sy1 + fystep;
   jstart := trunc(sy1);
   jend := trunc(sy2);
   devY1 := 1-sy1+jstart;
   devY2 := jend+1-sy2;
   pdx := pdy;
   for x := 0 to destwidth do        //horizontal destination pixels
    begin
     sx1 := fx * x;                        //x related values are repeated
     sx2 := sx1 + fxstep;                  //for each y and may be placed in
     istart := trunc(sx1);                 //lookup table
     iend := trunc(sx2);                   //...
     devX1 := 1-sx1+istart;                  //...
     devX2 := iend+1-sx2;                  //...
     destR := 0; destG := 0; destB := 0;   //clear destination colors
     psj := ps0-jstart*psStep;
     dy := devY1;
     for j := jstart to jend do  //vertical source pixels
      begin
       if j = jend then dy := dy - devY2;
       dyf := dy*fiy;
       psi := psj + (istart shl 2);
       dx := devX1;
       for i := istart to iend do //horizontal source pixels
        begin
         if i = iend then dx := dx - devX2;
         AP := dx*dyf*fix;
         color := PDW(psi)^;
         sB := color;
         destB := destB + sB*AP;
         sG := color shr 8;
         destG := destG + sG*AP;
         sR := color shr 16;
         destR := destR + sR*AP;
         inc(psi,4);
         dx := 1;
        end;//for i
       dec(psj,psStep);
       dy := 1;
      end;//for j
      sB := round(destB);
      color := sB or (sG shl 8) or (sR shl 16);
     PDW(pdx)^ := color;
     inc(pdx,4);
    end;//for x
   dec(pdy,pdstep);
  end;//for y
end;

end.
```

I'm trying to understand

```
type PDW = ^dword; ,inc(psi,4); and dec(psj,psStep);
```

meaning.

## add

I want to know the meaning of color = PDW(psi) ^ ;
If I want to apply some array variable then what am I supposed to do ?

That is came from delphi code. and I'm trying to convert in C.
I've never been touch the delphi code before.

Would you please help me to what do they mean and for convert in C?

Comment: `PDW = ^dword;` is a declaration of type `PDW` as a pointer to `DWORD`. `inc(psi,4);` is an incrementation of a value of the `psi` variable by 4. `dec(psj,psStep);` is a decrementation of a value of the `psj` variable by the value of `psStep` variable.

Comment: @Victoria I still didn;t get it. Would you let me know with example for understanding your comment?

Comment: Why not, for example `typedef DWORD *PDW;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Victoria says

```
type PDW = ^DWORD;
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef DWORD* PDW;
```

Also

```
inc(psi,4);
```

is equivalent to

```
psi+=4;
```

Likewise

```
dec(psj,psStep);
```

is equivalent to

```
psj-=psStep;
```

Finally

```
color = PDW(psi)^
```

is equivalent to

```
color = *((PDW)psi); // I think. It reads the DWORD value at address psi.
```

(all of the above only valid with the variable definitions as shown in the code)

Comment: Is PDW some kinds of array in C such as 'unsigned char tmp[]' ?

Comment: Pointers to data can be treated as if they are pointing to arrays of arrays. I suggest you learn about pointer arithmetic and how it works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Not quite. `Variables` that are of `type` "pointers to data" can be used as arrays. Not the type definition itself. PDW is not a variable - it is a type, and is thus not an array. But `variables` of that type can be used as one-dimensional arrays of the base type (DWORDs in this case).

Comment: @HeartWare: Remy is correct. Pointers to data can be treated like pointers to arrays. Pointers are variables, i.e. instances of the type ˋPointerˋ or of a typed pointer type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes, but `PDW` is not a pointer to data - it is a type definition. Therefore, PDW is _not_ "some kinds (sic) of array in C such as...". `psi` (which is of _type_ `PDW`), however, _is_ a "pointer to data" and can be used as a zero-based array to DWORDs.

Comment: @HeartWare: Just re-read what Remy said and then re-read your reply. And I am sure that Remy knows the difference between types and variables.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I have read (and re-read) what Remy said, and can only (re-)read it as a comment to my statement right above his - in which case my reply is relevant, since he's talking about _variables_ and I am talking about _types_, "and never the twain shall meet" - except in variable declarations :-) . And yes - I, too, am sure that Remy knows the difference, but perhaps others are not as well versed in the intricacies of the Delphi language as he and I...

Comment: He is talking about pointers. Pointers are variables of type Pointer or of a based pointer type and they can be treated as if they point to arrays. What he wrote was perfectly fine. A variable of type PDW (short form: a PDW) can also point to an array. Especially in translations from C, this is not uncommon.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: No one is disputing this (except that a `variable` of type `POINTER` can't point to an array in and off itself :-). It needs to point to a _type_ of some kind). My point is that a _variable_ of _type_ PDW can point to an array, but PDW itself cannot. I was talking about `PDW` (a _type_) and Remy's comment to that was about `Pointers to data`, which is a completely different beast (a _variable_). I was just pointing out the difference between the two.

Comment: An untyped pointer (a variable of type Pointer) can point to anything, so certainly to an array too. If people say "a PDW", they mean "a variable of type PDW", so if someone writes "a PDW points to a DWORD" they are saying "a variable of type PDW points to a variable or array of type DWORD". Clear now?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "An untyped pointer (a variable of type Pointer) can point to anything, so certainly to an array too.". If you want to get technical, then yes it _can_, but you can't _use_ it as an array (without casting it to another type), as you can with pointers that point to a specific type, ie. you can't say _PTR[37]_ on a pointer `variable` of `type` POINTER, but you _can_ on a pointer `variable` of `type` PDW (=^DWORD).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "If people say "a PDW", they mean "a variable of type PDW"" - Yes _a_ PDW is a `variable` of `type` _PDW_, but just plain _PDW_ is a `type` - not a `variable`. Thus the original question "Is PDW some kinds (sic) of array" can only be answered by "No", whereas "Is _a_ PDW (or PDWs) some kind of array" could be answered by "Yes".

Comment: @HeartWare: that is not what Remy wrote, so irrelevant.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: He wrote it as a reply to my comment, and thus should be understood in that context. When doing that, my subsequent comment was, IMNSHO, appropriate... YMMV, however...

Comment: Remy wrote: "Pointers to data can be treated as if they are pointing to arrays of arrays. I suggest you learn about pointer arithmetic and how it works." That is correct and there is nothing "not quite" about it. It doesn't even mention types or variables, so your comment on it is a complete non-sequitur.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Like I said: "thus should be understood in that context". You can't take his comment out of the context in which it was given and argue from that standpoint. But, as I (also) said, YMMV. We will simply have to agree to disagree on this...

Comment: The context is also irrelevant. His statement was simply correct.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Context is _never_ irrelevant.